# I am getting this error: Task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python, redis, fastapi, aioredis

```
from aioredis import (
    create_redis_pool
)

class RedisConn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None

    def set_conn(self, c):
        self.conn = c

    def get_conn(self):
        return self.conn


rdpsc = RedisConn()


async def init_redis_conn():
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = await create_redis_pool(
            'redis://localhost:6379',
            db=1
        )
        rdpsc.set_conn(connection)
    except Exception as excep:
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(excep)
```

I am getting this error `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`  while using `await init_redis_conn()`, I am using aioredis=1.3.1 with Python 3.8. Please help me thanks

Comment: "this error", what error ?

Comment: also as a side note instead of using those `get_` and `set_` methods use the `getter` and `setter` decorators

Comment: I am getting this error ERROR:    Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<RedisConnection._read_data() done, defined at /home/kanav/contract/thinkv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py:180> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f7b34450e20>()]> cb=[RedisConnection.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>() at /home/kanav/contract/thinkv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py:168]>